# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in AuthenticationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems, omniauth

I've almost got Omniauth w/ twitter working, however when it attempts to re-direct me to my app after validating twitter credntials I get the following long-winded error:

#### ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in AuthenticationsController#create

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "users" 
("created_at",  "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", 
"encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", 
"password_salt", "remember_created_at", "remember_token", 
 "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "updated_at") VALUES 
 (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    self.email = omniauth['info']['email'] if email.blank?
    authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])

  end

  def password_required?
    (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
  end

  def email_required?
    super && :provider.blank?
  end
end
```

Authentications controller:

```
    class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if p user user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the user.save portion to this:

```
p user
if user.save
```

which will log the contents of the user object to either your console or a log file (depending on how you're running Rails). You can then examine the output (which will resemble `#<User id: 15, sign_in_count: 3...`) to make sure all of the columns listed in the SQLite error have sensible values. You may find, for example, that "email" is required in your database, but that your user has a nil for email.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the modified authentications controller (added p user before user.save) but unfortunately the same error peaked it's ugly head up again.

Comment: Hi Tony,
I meant the addition as more of a debug message, I'll update my answer with some details.